# C Reallocation of 2d array function

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, 2d, realloc

My reallocation does not work (Segmentation fault for 11.element), I would like to enlarge the array twice, the length of the column is constant according to the first input.I would like to allocate in function.
In the function vztvorPole I allocate an array of 10 rows and x columns.

```
 char vytvorPole(char ***grid, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    *grid = malloc( sizeof(*grid)*nrows);
    
    if (*grid == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++)
    {
        (*grid)[i]=(char *) malloc (ncols*sizeof(*grid));
        if((*grid)[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
    char realokuj(char ***grid, int nrows, int ncols)
    {
        char **docasne;
        docasne = (char**)realloc (*grid, nrows*sizeof(*grid));
        
        for(int i=nrows/2;i<nrows;i++)
        {
            (docasne)[i]=(char *) malloc (ncols*sizeof(*grid));
            
        }
        *grid = docasne;
    }
    int main (void)
    {
        char **diagonaly;
        int rDiagonaly = 10;
        int cDiagonaly = -1;
    
        char *str = NULL;
        size_t  capacity = 0;
        int first = 1;
        int nr = 0;
        
        printf("Vypln:\n");
        while ( getline (&str, &capacity, stdin) != -1)
        {
            if(str[0] == '\n')
                    break;

            if (first)
            {
                cDiagonaly = strlen (str);
                vytvorPole(&diagonaly, rDiagonaly, cDiagonaly);
                first = 0;
            }   
        
            if (nr==rDiagonaly)
                {
                    rDiagonaly *= 2; 
                    realokuj(&diagonaly, rDiagonaly, cDiagonaly);
                }
            
            strcpy(diagonaly[nr],str);
            nr++;
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think it "does not work"?

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped) for 11. element

Comment: To start with, the two `sizeof(*grid)` in your function are wrong! The first should be `sizeof(**grid)` and the second should be `sizeof(***grid)`, unless I am much mistaken.

Comment: Since you're doing `getline` for input data, can you post [in a separate code block], the input data you're using that causes the segfault?

Comment: Which _line_ causes the segfault? If you compile with `-g` to get debugging symbols, you can invoke with (e.g.) `gdb ./myprogram`. Then, do `run`. When the segfault occurs, do `bt` to get a stack traceback. That should show what line was the issue. You can check the value of the [relevant] variables.

Comment: gdb writes strcpy(diagonaly[nr],str);

Comment: For completeness, I added the function vytvorPole

Comment: @AdrianMole 
Do you think that the function vytvorPole is wrong?

Comment: Yes. But, in the first case, `*grid` and `**grid` are both pointers, and will likely be the same size. But, when you allocate memory for plain `char` data, you are allocating space for `n` *pointers* rather than `n` *characters*. But it ain't the cause of your segfault.

Comment: If I have ten inputs it works normally, for eleven it falls.

Comment: You set `cDiagnonaly` _only_ on the first input line. This assumes that the first line is the _largest_ [or that _all_ lines are the same length--or less]? Is this the case?

Comment: all are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit more complicated than needed.

If you *initialize* `diagnonaly` (e.g. `char **diagnoaly = NULL;`), you can eliminate `vytvorPole` and just use `realokuj`. That is, if you also do: `int rDiagonaly = 0;`

That's because `realloc` will handle a `NULL` pointer just fine (i.e. it's equivalent to `malloc` in that case).

And, you don't need to do:

```
(docasne)[i]=(char *) malloc (ncols*sizeof(*grid));
```

in the subfunction.

It's better to use `strdup` in `main`. If we do that, we don't need `cDiagonaly` at all. And, we can have strings of varying lengths.

Passing a triple star pointer (e.g. `char ***grid`) has issues. You could just pass it as `char **` and use `return` to update the value since you don't really use the existing return.

But, this can really be done from `main` *without* a separate function.

While it *may* be possible to fix your existing code, it really should be simplified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
#if 0
    char **diagonaly;
    int rDiagonaly = 10;
#else
    char **grid = NULL;
    int rmax = 0;
#endif
#if 0
    int cDiagonaly = -1;
#endif

    char *str = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 0;
#if 0
    int first = 1;
#endif
    int nr = 0;

    printf("Vypln:\n");
    while (getline(&str,&capacity,stdin) != -1) {
        if (str[0] == '\n')
            break;

        if (nr == rmax) {
            rmax += 100;

            grid = realloc(grid,sizeof(*grid) * (rmax + 1));
            if (grid == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(1);
            }

            // this is similar to what you did, but it's not necessary because
            // of "grid[nr] = NULL;" below
#if 0
            for (int idx = nr;  idx < rmax;  ++idx)
                grid[idx] = NULL;
#endif
        }

        grid[nr++] = strdup(str);
        grid[nr] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the cleaned up version [*without* the `cpp` conditionals]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char **grid = NULL;
    int rmax = 0;

    char *str = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 0;
    int nr = 0;

    printf("Vypln:\n");
    while (getline(&str,&capacity,stdin) != -1) {
        if (str[0] == '\n')
            break;

        if (nr == rmax) {
            rmax += 100;

            grid = realloc(grid,sizeof(*grid) * (rmax + 1));
            if (grid == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        grid[nr++] = strdup(str);
        grid[nr] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can see what I added (answer). I'm not sure if I'd use yours the way I need to

Comment: They are now essentially the same (_except_ that you use `malloc` on the first allocation). So, I'm not sure how you think they're different. Are you having trouble understanding the `#if 0`? It's just to show old vs. new code (it's eliminated by `cpp`).

Comment: I haven't programmed for very long, so I haven't met much with it, thank you anyway

Comment: Well, good luck. Everybody starts sometime. It _does_ get easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like that okay?

```
while ( getline (&str, &capacity, stdin) != -1)
    {
        if(str[0] == '\n')
            break;
        
        
        if (first)
        {
            cDiagonaly = strlen (str);
            diagonaly = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*diagonaly)*rDiagonaly);
            
        
        if (nr==rDiagonaly)
            {
                rDiagonaly *= 2; 
                docasne = (char**)realloc (diagonaly, rDiagonaly*sizeof(*diagonaly));
                diagonaly=docasne;
            }
        
        diagonaly[nr]=(char*) malloc (cDiagonaly*sizeof(**diagonaly));
        strcpy(diagonaly[nr],str);
        
        nr++;
        
    }
```